# problems with renaming ListView in xml file

Tags: android

I am playing around with ListView in android and I have a simple class that extends ListActivity.

Whenever I change the name of the ListView in xml file from `android:list` to something else my program crashes.

Here is my ListActivity code:

```
private NewExpenseScreenModel mDbAdabter;

    String[] items = { "Category", "Month", "Year"};
       /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.statistics);

        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(
                this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, 
                items);

        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        mDbAdabter = new NewExpenseScreenModel(this);

        populateFields();


    }

    private void populateFields() 
    {
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spending_row, mDbAdabter.getAllCategories());
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

and here is my xml file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:padding="10dip"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Spinner
       android:id="@+id/spinner"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:prompt="@string/spinner_title"
   />
    <ListView android:id="@+id/android:list" android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:layout_width="match_parent"></ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

any idea what is going on.. 
I want to implement a onItemClickedListener later on so I want to be able to find the ListView by id. 
I dont really understand why i cannot just change the id

Additional Info:

I also have another class that uses a different xml file with a list id="android:list" but I never need to find that listView by id so its not a problem. 
The other class uses the same xml file to describe layout of each row.

**Update:**

I managed to access the id by using `findViewById(android.R.id.list);` instead of `findViewById(R.id.list);` but i still dont understand why it wont let me rename the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list view id should be `@android:id/list`.

You use `+` in id when you define a new id. Since you are using ListView id of the listview should have `list` and `list` id is already defined internally, so no need to add `+`.

**Edited**

The above is mandatory when you extend the class from `ListActivity`. See @Mejonzhan answer why so.

Now, if you want your own id or when you want to have many List Views, then do not extend ListActivity instead extend Activity and handle the ListViews as below:

Change id as follows:

`<ListView android:id="@+id/myListView"`

And in the code, access the list view as follows:

ListView myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myListView)

Comment: Ok. yet this doesnt explain why i cannot change the name does it?

Comment: @Xitcod13 updated my answer for having your own id for listview.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item_1, 
               items);`, in place of `` `ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, 
               items); `` `

Comment: simple_spinner_item_1 just underlines red. So i guess its not the solution

Answer (score 0):

[ListActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html) has a default layout that consists of a single, full-screen list in the center of the screen. However, if you desire, you can customize the screen layout by setting your own view layout with setContentView() in onCreate(). **To do this, your own view MUST contain a ListView object with the id "@android:id/list" (or list if it's in code)**

ListActivity extend Activity, you can search the source code ,find the ListActivity, and find the function:

```
public void onContentChanged() {
239        super.onContentChanged();
240        View emptyView = findViewById(com.android.internal.R.id.empty);
241        mList = (ListView)findViewById(com.android.internal.R.id.list);
242        if (mList == null) {
243            throw new RuntimeException(
244                    "Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is " +
245                    "'android.R.id.list'");
246        }
247        if (emptyView != null) {
248            mList.setEmptyView(emptyView);
249        }
250        mList.setOnItemClickListener(mOnClickListener);
251        if (mFinishedStart) {
252            setListAdapter(mAdapter);
253        }
254        mHandler.post(mRequestFocus);
255        mFinishedStart = true;
256    }
```

in  line 241        mList = (ListView)findViewById(com.android.internal.R.id.list);
so you can not change the list name

Comment: Can i Have multiple ListView objects in the xml file??